# db2 cannot drop foreign key with lowercase name

Tags: foreign-keys, db2

I am trying to drop a foreign key in DB2 through the command line. I have succeeded in this many times and I am sure that I am using the correct syntax:

```
db2 "alter table TABLENAME drop constraint fk_keyname"
```

Output:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "FK_KEYNAME" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
```

All my foreign keys are created with an uppercase name. Except for the key I now want to drop. I don't know how to got created with a lowercase name but it seems that it will not drop keys that are lowercase.

When I try to add this foreign key (while it still exists) I get the following message:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0601N  The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing 
name "fk_keyname" of type "FOREIGN KEY".  SQLSTATE=42710
```

Does anyone know how to drop foreign keys that have a lowercase name?

The answer by mustaccio worked. Tried all kinds of quotes but this way did the trick:

```
db2 'alter table TABLENAME drop constraint "fk_keyname"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 will convert object names to uppercase, unless they are quoted. Generally it's not a very good idea to create objects with lower- or mixed-case names. If your foreign key is actually "fk_keyname" (all lowercase), run `db2 "alter table TABLENAME drop constraint \"fk_keyname\""` or `db2 'alter table TABLENAME drop constraint "fk_keyname"'`

This behaviour is not unique to DB2, by the way.